# Spree change default currency and Country

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I am developing an e-commerce application using Spree for India. So all prices are in 'Rs' and states and zones are India related. I edited them easily in Spree 1.2.0 but I couldn't find those options in 1.1.3. How to customize this in 1.1.3

Answer (score 19):

You can set these options in your `app/config/initializers/spree.rb`

```
Spree.config do |config|

  # Set country name and currency like this (Note: you will need to
  # run 'rake db:seed' before this. Change country name in
  # Spree::Country.find_by_name('Germany') replace Germany to your desired one)

  config.currency = 'EUR'
  country = Spree::Country.find_by_name('Germany')
  config.default_country_id = country.id if country.present?

  # You can also set following options too.

  config.site_name = "Todo Store"
  config.override_actionmailer_config = true
  config.enable_mail_delivery = true
end
```

Comment: Really useful thanks. Is there a list somewhere of other things that you can configure this way? I'm thinking whether you show 'state' etc.

Comment: This caused db:schema:load to fail. Changing the last line to `end if Spree::Country.table_exists?` fixes it

Comment: Note: it is actually config/initializers/spree.rb  (I tried to change it but the edit was rejected) Anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You can set these options in your app/config/initializers/spree.rb

```
Spree.config do |config|
  config.currency = 'Rs'  
  config.default_country_id = 105 # Your default country id 
end
```